# Non-clustered index on column in a small table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, database-design, indexing

I have the following table, `ReportType`.  This table will only ever have 100 or so rows and is never updated by the application (so `INSERT`, `UPDATE` or `DELETE` performance is not an issue).

```
Table: ReportType
===========================================================
|  ID (PK)  |  Name  |  ExportFormat  |  SourceDatabase   |
===========================================================
```

Is it still worth putting a non-clustered index on `ExportFormat`?  This column is used as a filter criteria in some scenarios and in some reports.  It isn't highly selective at all (there are maybe only 10 distinct values) which indicates that it would not make a good candidate for a non-clustered index.  BUT this table never experiences any `INSERT`, `UPDATE` or `DELETE` operations, so surely an index would actually benefit here (even if only slightly)?

Comment: If the table has records then it has experienced an insert.

Comment: "so surely an index would actually benefit here (even if only slightly)" - remember, every NC index lookup results in a bookmark lookup to obtain the remaining columns, unless it's a covering index (which isn't what you proposed). So, no, it's not necessarily a benefit even if the table is only ever read from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I disagree with the answer you accepted.

You say this table is read only so I don't see a downside of creating a **covering** non clustered index as below.

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX 
     ON  ReportType(ExportFormat) INCLUDE(ID,Name,SourceDatabase )
```

For such a small amount of rows the benefit may be quite marginal but it avoids having to process **all** the rows for every query filtering on `ExportFormat`

Answer (score 3):

As a rule of thumb, an index on a table with less than 128 rows adds more overhead than it's worth.  Especially a non-clustered index-- a single bookmark lookup is probably more expansive than scanning the entire table.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  And let's say there are 150 rows... would it then be worthwhile to add the index on such a column?

Comment: There are no hard rules.  Personally, I would not add an index until I had actual proof of a performance issue.  That is a query plan with a slowdown, or a reproducible test set that improves noticeably better  with the index enabled.